# Sidecar Constantly Crashes in Congested Network Environments

Tags: network, wifi, crash, sidecar

When I use Sidecar between my **M1 Air** and my **2nd Gen Ipad Pro 12.9"** at coffeeshops, I get near constant crashes and poor connectivity, whereas it works much better at home.

I downloaded a wifi analyzer app to look at the network bands, and found that I only have performance issues when there is another local wifi network which projects on the same band as the network I am currently on. (using WiFi Explorer Lite)
[image: Network Analyzer]

So I bought a portable router, and manually configured the band to be 20Mhz and to be on a channel that ostensibly looks the clearest. For some time, this has improved my Sidecar performance, but it is still not perfect.

Sometimes it will work perfectly after failing to start it several times, and others I will not be able to get it to work no matter what I do. I've noticed I always fail to start it if I have a Zoom meeting in progress.

I had previously determined that Sidecar fails most when the ping is most unreliable. I did repeated ping tests and found that I have a really poor average ping at the coffeeshop I'm at as shown here:
[image]

I suspect Sidecar times out and crashes if the ping is too high, with a maximum shown here of 600Ms, and a 90Ms standard deviation for the packet ping, which is terrible. How can I make the ping more stable in a congested environment, and how can I get better Sidecar performance is congested network environments?

Thank so much in advance! Sidecar is such a pivotal feature, if only it worked!!

Comment: Public ping in interesting, and there is a public routing element because of the Apple Account negotiation, but that should only be during session setup, not ongoing after it's established. You should ping something else on your local network instead and see if there is latency even locally. If so, it's your own hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using it with a wired connection. I bought a 18w tiny PD Charger, a 10' usb C cable to connect the charger to my M1 Air, and a 3' USB C to lightning to connect the M1 Air to my Ipad.

With this setup, sidecar works 100% of the time and the hardware required is pretty light and compact.

With a more power hungry Mac, replace the 18w PD charger with a charger sufficient for your Mac.